# WP: setting with_front to false and removing post type slug

Tags: wordpress, url, url-rewriting

For one of my specific post types I am trying to remove the default permalink structure by doing:

```
 add_filter('register_post_type_args', function($args, $post_type) {
    if ('procedures' === $post_type ) {
      $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
    }
    return $args;
 }, 99, 2);
```

Which works fine. Then I am also trying to remove the post type slug from the URL with the following:

```
function remove_procedures_slug($post_link, $post, $leavename) {
   if ($post->post_type != 'procedures' || $post->post_status != 'publish') {
    return $post_link;
   }

   $post_link = str_replace('/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link);
   return $post_link;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'remove_procedures_slug', 10, 3);

function set_procedures_url($query) {
  if(isset($query->query['post_type'])) {
    return;
  }

  if (!empty($query->query['name'])) {
    $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'procedures', 'page'));
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'set_procedures_url');
```

This works fine when removing the `register_post_type_args` filter. How do I accomplish changing /blog/procedures/page-1 to just /page-1?

If I do something like this:

```
if ('procedures' === $post_type && is_array($args)) {
  $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
  $args['rewrite']['slug'] = '/';
}
```

That works but removes the archive page. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the current request is for the archive using [`is_post_type_archive()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_post_type_archive/)? Perhaps something like the following:

```
if( 'procedures' === $post_type && is_array($args) && !is_post_type_archive('procedures') ){
    $args['rewrite']['with_front'] = false;
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = '/';
}
```

Comment: Although that seems like that would work, it did not :(